# Split a large zip file in small chunks using php script

Tags: php, file, split

I am using below script for spliting a large zip file in small chucks.

```
$filename = "pro.zip"; 
$targetfolder = '/tmp';

// File size in Mb per piece/split. 
// For a 200Mb file if piecesize=10 it will create twenty 10Mb files
$piecesize = 10; // splitted file size in MB


$buffer = 1024;
$piece = 1048576*$piecesize;
$current = 0;
$splitnum = 1;

if(!file_exists($targetfolder)) {
    if(mkdir($targetfolder)) {
        echo "Created target folder $targetfolder".br();
    }
}

if(!$handle = fopen($filename, "rb")) {
    die("Unable to open $filename for read! Make sure you edited filesplit.php correctly!".br());
}

$base_filename = basename($filename);

$piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
if(!$fw = fopen($piece_name,"w")) {
    die("Unable to open $piece_name for write. Make sure target folder is writeable.".br());
}
echo "Splitting $base_filename into $piecesize Mb files ".br()."(last piece may be smaller in size)".br();
echo "Writing $piece_name...".br();
while (!feof($handle) and $splitnum < 999) {
    if($current < $piece) {
        if($content = fread($handle, $buffer)) {
            if(fwrite($fw, $content)) {
                $current += $buffer;
            } else {
                die("filesplit.php is unable to write to target folder");
            }
        }
    } else {
        fclose($fw);
        $current = 0;
        $splitnum++;
        $piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "Writing $piece_name...".br();
        $fw = fopen($piece_name,"w");
    }
}
fclose($fw);
fclose($handle);
echo "Done! ".br();
exit;

function br() {
    return (!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']))?'<br>':"\n";
}
?>
```

But this script not creating small files after split in target temp folder. Script runs successfully without any error.

Please help me to found out what is issue here? Or If you have any other working script for similar functinality, Please provide me.

Comment: why not calling `exec('split')`?

Comment: don't know about that Please explain here or in answer

Comment: since you mention a tmp dir and / filesep, can we assume a *nix Operating system, and your code doesn't need to be portable?   If so then as @WebnetMobile.com says look into split `man split `  from a command prompt/shell/terminal.  It will take a file and split it into multiple smaller files for you.

Comment: you need to join all the files back into 1 to unzip it, you can use `cat` to do this.  cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 > file.zip .OR are you looking to break 1 large zip file into spanning zip file( where it will ask you for next piece, etc...)

Comment: @Doon Can you please elborate to me

Comment: @samad Elaborate what exactly. most of it is covered in my answer below.

Comment: @Doon where do i apply this `split -b50m filename x`

Comment: actually i have a lunix server and i want to this implement @Doon

Comment: how this worked for me @Doon

Comment: you would need to call it via exec, or wrap it in a shellscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments above, you can use `split` to split a file into smaller pieces, and can then use `cat` to join them back together.

```
split -b50m filename x
```

and to put them back

```
 cat xaa xab xac > filename
```

If you are looking to split the zipfile into a spanning type archive, so that you do not need to rejoin the them together  take a look at `zipsplit`

```
 zipslit -n (size) filename
```

so you can just call zipsplit from your exec script and then most standard unzip utils should be able to put it back together.  `man zipslit` for more options, including setting output path, etc..

Comment: Shall I use it like this `exec(split -b50m filename x)` in php script ?

Comment: `exec('/path/to/split -b50M filename part');`  would work the part is what to call the parts it generates, but I am thinking that you probably want `exec('zipsplit -n50m -b /tmp pro.zip`); `

Comment: tried `exec('zipsplit -n50m -b /tmp pro.zip');` but this has done nothing. I am running code on xampp (windows OS)

Comment: Err See my original Comment, It was based on *nix os (assumption based on /tmp and the file sep. Take a look at http://www.info-zip.org for Windows/DOS versions of the zip tools.

Comment: zipsplit works only for files < 2GB